# How to implement a different certificate validation in XSdES4J

Tags: xades4j

I'm using XAdES to validate message which are using xades-t.
But some counrties in europe do not rely on the certificate chain to a valid root CA.
How would I go about in implementing a different way of validating certificates in xades4j?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

When you create a [XadesVerificationProfile](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/verification/XadesVerificationProfile.html) you must supply a [CertificateValidationProvider](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/providers/CertificateValidationProvider.html). The library includes an implementation based on Java's PKIX classes, but you can implement another provider with custom validation login and supply it to the XadesVerificationProfile constructor.